# Objectify paging

Tags: java, google-app-engine, paging, objectify

Can you find a good tutorial or documentation about achieving a good pagination in a Google App Engine Objectify world?

I found some posts:
http://groups.google.com/group/objectify-appengine/browse_thread/thread/b640b5d377b620b4

But nothing seems to help me. Is there some sort of LIMIT query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The post you linked to describes the correct way to do pagination: Using cursors. You can fetch using offsets and limits, but it's inefficient and should be avoided.