# Getting cursor with Objectify without iterating through items

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, paging, objectify

I want to execute a query, get the results and then get the cursor to the next item if there is any. The only relevant post I found was: [Objectify paging with Cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027202/objectify-paging-with-cursors)

Is there a way of doing this without iterating through the items?

```
Query<User> query = ofy().load().type(User.class).limit(RecordLimit).filter("gameId", gameId);
//execute and get the results
List<User> users = query.list()
//get the cursor for the next user
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String cursor = query.iterator().getCursor().toWebSafeString();
```

Look at these [unit tests](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/blob/master/src/test/java/com/googlecode/objectify/test/QueryCursorTestsBig.java) to make things a bit more clear.

Answer (score -2):

`Query` is itself iterable - like a cursor.

You can directly do:

```
Query<User> query = blah;
for(User u: query) {
    //u is next item from the "cursor"
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't solve my problem. I don't want to iterate   through the results.

Comment: You can try: query.iterator().next() to get the "next item, if any". Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: He is wanting `iterator.getCursor().toWebSafeString()` without ever having to care about the interator. This can be done in JDO so i would be shocked if not the much better Ofy. But i can't figure it out either, did you ever?